# Django FE + BackEnd integration

Tags: django, reactjs

I started up a project in django. It is still not very big but it has some 5 apps already active . 
The project was done in django backend and in the html. the FE is plain JS and CSS - the FE code is in every app.

I heard\read that react\angular are far more popular for FE and have many benefits and I know django can work with them (But needs some adjustments made to it).

my question is, is project like mine - that keeps all the login in django without using a JS framework - scalable\preferable?

should I make the effort to refactor my code to django+react (so I wont have to do it later)?

and how hard is it to make that move?

best practices \ references to articles will be appreciated (looked for it but didnt find anything that really meets my needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build your api's and also check this tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIFqqdRxmVo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHhQRHE8IR8

I think it is better to seprate **T** from **MV** in your Codes and Using some frontend Library or framwork